# I tried correct way of installing passport, but cant install as it says "oauth_clients" table not found

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I once deleted all the passport tables from the database. And then tried installing the laravel passport again but running command php artisan passport:install **throws "oauth_clients" table not found**. Running command php artisan migrate after running command composer require laravel/passport says **nothing to migrate** then running php artisan passport:install throws table not found error.

Comment: Laravel keeps information about migrations in `migrations` table in your database. Manually removing tables does not change this table, so laravel thinks that thers is nothing to migrate. Next time you should use artisan command to remove tables.

Comment: I solved by creating the new laravel project and installing the passport. Then I copied the new migration files created during the installations to the project I was working on. Then running php artisan migrate created all these tables like 'oauth_clients', 'oauth_personal_tokens'. And I was able to install the passport.